# Double Atwood machine problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, string

[image: double Atwood machine]

Here $m_2=2$kg, $m_3=3$kg, $m_1=x$
We've got to find $m_1$ such that $m_1$ remains at rest.
I've used the double Atwood machine formula:

$$\displaystyle \frac {-g(4m_2m_3-3m_1m_3+m_1m_2)}{(m_1m_2+m_1m_3+4m_2m_3)}=0$$

However I get the wrong result every time I do so($3.428$kg)
Is there any alternative way to solve it?

Comment: It looks like you tried summing the formulae for the acceleration of both left and right pulleys and setting their sum to zero, resulting in a formula that doesn't describe anything at all. It's always important to know what a formula means and ideally how it's derived before applying it. In this case you're given the value of the acceleration of the left hand pulley, so that's the formula you need to start with.

Comment: Hi MsBonniePython. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simpler if you work from first principles.

If $m_1$ does not move then the tension in the upper string must be $T_1=m_1g$. Also, the pulley on the other end of the upper string does not move, so the net force on it must be zero. If the tension in the lower string is $T_2$ then this tells us that

$$2T_2 = T_1 \\ \Rightarrow T_2 = \frac 1 2 T_1 = \frac 1 2 m_1g$$

From this we can calculate the accelerations of $m_2$ and $m_3$:-

$$m_2a_2 = T_2 - m_2g 
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow a_2 = \frac {T_2}{m_2} - g = \frac {m_1}{2m_2}g - g$$

$$m_3a_3 = m_3g - T_2\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow a_3 = g - \frac {T_2}{m_3} = g- \frac {m_1}{2m_3}g$$

But since $m_2$ and $m_3$ are connected by a single piece of string, $a_2$ and $a_3$ must be the same, so

$$\displaystyle \frac {m_1}{2m_2} - 1 = 1 - \frac {m_1}{2m_3}$$

The rest is just algebra - I'll let you do that for yourself.